# What language(s) are used to create the Google self driving car software?

Tags: programming-languages, artificial-intelligence

I have searched but have not been able to find any information about this. Also interested in the overall architecture of the system from a software point of view. They pull together a pretty significant amount of information from the rader / laser / GPS and tire tracking in real time to build and maintain a "model of the world" - I'm curious what the used to create this.

Comment: You might find [this article](http://spectrum.ieee.org/automaton/robotics/artificial-intelligence/how-google-self-driving-car-works/) interesting.

Comment: Michael, that's funny - I just watched this video which is what spurred me to ask this question! The video gave a good overview of the project but didn't get into the software (that I saw anyway)

Comment: I haven't actually watched the view yet. I just happened to see this posted on HN this morning.

Comment: About the programming languages: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QFDBs7kJLhM&feature=player_embedded#t=230s

Comment: @EugenConstantinDinca - so C++ is the answer, post it as an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

About the programming languages: as Sebastian Thrun states in one of the office hours sessions for Udacity's "CS373: Programming A Robotic Car" [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QFDBs7kJLhM&feature=player_embedded#t=230s):

> almost all the code is written in C++.

Answer (score 10):

Why does programming languages attract you when you are researching on Google Self Driving Car Software? IMHO the Algorithms will be more fascinating to look at as compared to whether its written using C++ or Python or LISP.

For an example Google Map Reduce was written in C++. Open Source community read the research paper, understood the Algorithm, concluded its all about breaking the problem into a data-parallel Algorithm and then just wrote it in Java which popularly came to be known as Apache Hadoop. So it was never about C++ or Java it was all about solving Data Parallel problems.

Comment: I agree with you mostly, I am interested in the algorithms used. I guess I'm interested in the language because I would imagine the code base is large, very complex, written by many people and reliability is pretty important so I'm curious how they broke it down into pieces, I guess the language is just one part of that!

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Although most production code must be written in c++, python should have been used a lot too during model training and experimenting phase.